# Graphics Disappear in Panel on scrolling

Tags: vb.net, system.drawing

I have the code

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

    Using myPen As New Pen(Drawing.Color.BurlyWood, 6)


        If upTimer.Enabled = True Then

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x1, y2)

        End If
        If leftTimer.Enabled = True Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x2, y1)
        End If
        If rightTimer.Enabled = True Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x2, y1)
        End If
        If downTimer.Enabled = True Then

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x1, y2)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Where x1,y1,x2 and y2 are initalized to zero in form_load.

Timers code are:

```
  Private Sub upTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

    y2 = y2 + 5

End Sub
 Private Sub leftTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles leftTimer.Tick
    x2 = x2 - 5 

End Sub
Private Sub rightTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rightTimer.Tick

    x2 = x2 + 5
End Sub
 Private Sub downTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles downTimer.Tick

    y2 = y2 - 5 
End Sub
```

I've four buttons to enable these four timers.Now the problem is that when I scroll the picturebox contained in a panel automatically or manually the drawings get disappeared.How can I avoid this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this workaround:

```
Private Sub Panel1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Scroll
   PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

But when you scroll the panel, the picturebox must refresh itself. I tried this with a simple test: I added a global variable "count" in the "paint" event of the picturebox then I added +1 to "count" variable and printed this value (from the paint event) to a label in the form. The counter must incrase for each scroll.

Comment: I tried PictureBox1.Refresh() in panel scroll event but again same thing is happening.The lines are getting disappeared.I want to add that the timer (one at a time is constantly running).

Comment: In any case, add the refresh also on timers, but I think (IMHO) you'are wrong the logic. Try these changes: In paint event add only one drawline, add only one timer, and add 4 boolean global variable. Set the boolean variable at true or false on your buttons (ex: btn1 set blnDirectionUP=true), in the timer you check your boolean values and chenge the x2/y2 and finaly on the end of timer tick and of scroll event, you add the refresh of picturebox. If I understand what you do, that's all. :)